# custom templated lockguard illigal global destructor

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a template lockguard for a custom R/W Lock. I want it templated so that I can use the guard for different rw locks, but I can't get it to work. I'm getting the errors like:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    jimdbMSVS   d:\...\src\thread\rwlockguard.hpp   6
Error   C2588   '::~RWLockGuard': illegal global destructor jimdbMSVS   d:\...\src\thread\rwlockguard.hpp   20
Error   C2433   'RWLockGuard': 'inline' not permitted on data declarations  jimdbMSVS   d:\...\src\thread\rwlockguard.hpp   6
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   jimdbMSVS   d:\...\src\thread\rwlockguard.hpp   21
Error   C2059   syntax error: '<'   jimdbMSVS   d:\git_repo\jim-db\src\thread\rwlockguard.hpp   6
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '<'    jimdbMSVS   d:\...\src\thread\rwlockguard.hpp   6
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    jimdbMSVS   d:\...\src\thread\rwlockguard.hpp   21
Error   C2988   unrecognizable template declaration/definition  jimdbMSVS   d:\...\src\thread\rwlockguard.hpp   6
```

I know that i need to enforce the 4 methods but i dont know how todo it right and how i get this to work. So what have i done wrong/right?

Header:

```
#pragma once
#include "rwlock.h"
namespace jimdb{ namespace tasking {
   enum LockType
   {
       READ,
       WRITE
   };

   template<typename T = RWLock>
   class RWLockGuard{
   public:
      inline RWLockGuard(T& lock, const LockType& l);
      inline ~RWLockGuard();

   private:
      T& m_lock;
      LockType m_type;
   };
}} // jimdb::tasking
#include "rwlockguard.hpp"
```

and the hpp:

```
namespace jimdb{ namespace tasking {
   template<typename T>
   inline RWLockGuard<T>::RWLockGuard(T& lock, const LockType& l) : m_lock(lock), m_type(l)
   {
      switch(m_type)
      {
      case READ:
         m_lock.readLock();
         break;
      case WRITE:
         m_lock.writeLock();
         break;
      }
   }

   template<typename T>
   inline RWLockGuard<T>::~RWLockGuard()
   {
      switch (m_type)
      {
      case READ:
         m_lock.readUnlock();
         break;
      case WRITE:
         m_lock.writeUnlock();
         break;
      }
   }
}} // jimdb::tasking
```

rwlock.h

```
namespace jimdb{ namespace tasking {
   class RWLock {
    public:
        inline RWLock();
        inline void readLock();
        inline void readUnlock();
        inline void writeLock();
        inline void writeUnlock();
    private:
        int m_reader;
        bool m_writing;
        std::condition_variable m_cond;
        std::mutex m_mutex;
    };
}} // jimdb::tasking
```

The goal would be:

```
RWLockGuard<RWLock> lock(mylock,READ);
```

Comment: what is the content of `rwlock.h`? please post a [MCVE].

Comment: added the header. Its a class that has the 2 lock/unlock methods

Comment: [this code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SwALN3wvqxJ0szc7) compiles using clang

Comment: but i cant compile it always getting the error above

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: the custom compiler of visual studio 2015 so vc140.  I am confused. It compiles at http://melpon.org

Comment: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Dr5lgrmUYBu55fAF this is how i have the code.

Comment: did you try writing the definition of the member functions directly in the class declaration? maybe VS mixes something up there

Comment: @BennX: You are including `rwlockguard.hpp` at the end of `rwlockguard.h`, are you also excluding `rwlockguard.hpp` from the project? Otherwise you will get a circular reference.

Comment: @AndyG no i didn't i did the include after the ns because vs sometimes doesnt get it then.

Comment: @m.s. i tested it. And you were right that it worked. Now i deleted the hpp file (it was a renamed cpp) and included directly a hpp and included inside of the ns (right after definition) now it compiles just fine. I start hating vs...